# Is accelerometer taking as much power (current) as it needs?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, oscilloscope, accelerometer

I want to connect accelerometer to an oscilloscope. I have 3x AA rechargable batteries (2550mAh).

I was told that e.g. microcontroller knows how much amps should it take and it wont burn if I connect it to those batteries.

But e.g. LED would burn. What about accelerometer? Is it able to take as much amps as it needs or should I use resistor?

Any other advices and tutorials provided regarding accelerometer+microcontroller or accelerometer+oscilloscope are appreciated.

This is my accelerometer (ebay title): GY-521 6 DOF MPU-6050 Module 3 Axis Accelerometer Gyroscope Module for Arduino

Will it work also with Atmega32 even though it's written there for Arduino?

Comment: Read the datasheet. It's never a good idea to expect the device to protect itself and don't trust everything you are told.

Comment: I don't have any datasheet to the accelerometers, they are bought from ebay, and letters on it are so small I cant read them ... :D that's why I have asked.

Comment: If you don't know what accelerometer you have how do you expect to get data from it? Can you at least provide the link to the eBay listing?

Comment: Please check edit.

Comment: I'll hazard an advice:  **No datasheet => No sale**.  Besides, EE.SE is *not* a volunteer support desk for your eBay seller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already used one of those modules. It can be powered with a voltage from 3V up to 5V.

It can virtually work with any microcontroller that have a I<sup>2</sup>C peripheral.

Be aware that you need to write some values to its configuration registers before you can get any data from it.

The accelerometer reference is MPU-6050, you can look for the datasheet on the Internet. There is one covering the registers and other covering its general characteristics.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, I have checked the datasheet and its saying Operating Voltages 2.375 to 3.46 V, If I connect 3AA batteries, will it burn? By the way if you would be so kind can you answer the question: Will it burn if I dont lower the current? Or it can take as much current as it needs (as it is in microcontroller)? I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: The accelerometer indeed can operate up to 3.46V but the module you are using has an integrated voltage regulator that can support 5V.

Comment: Super, thank you. Now I just need to find out what to connect where. If you know where I can find some tutorial, or if it is in datasheet, feel free to answer. Besides that I am marking your answer as correct. :)

Comment: I never worked with Atmel microcontrollers so I'm no sure if the Atmega32 has a I2C peripheral, if it has you will have to identify the SDA and SCL pins and connect them to the accelerometer. If the Atmega32 does not have an I2C peripheral you can always implement a software based one, in that case you are free to choose the pins you want as SDA and SCL.

Comment: Aren't you inderested in beuing my tutor just for few explanations? I will pay you. Please contact me on zatokar1 skype. Thanks! :) I am java developer and know just a little about all that so I need someone like u.

Comment: Sorry, since I'm not a native english speaker so I don't feel comfortable talking in english, although we can discuss this further by e-mail if it is ok for you.